# How to Insert Background Image in One Page Wonder Bootstrap template?

Tags: html, css, templates, sass, vs-web-site-project

I'm building from the One Page Wonder Bootstrap template: https://startbootstrap.com/themes/one-page-wonder/

I can't figure out how to insert a background image in the masthead. Has anyone had experience with this?

Thank you!

Comment: `background-image: url('http//example.com/image.png');` is the standard approach. Have you tried that? What have you already tried? Can you please add your existing code to your question?

Comment: Can you provide what you've already tried? Some code samples, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a good bit of the masthead content with this rule.

```
header.masthead .masthead-content {
  background-image: url('http//example.com/image.png');
}
```

Replacing the entire masthead is more complex, though.  You would probably want to start with editing the HTML to remove the `bg-circle` elements to give you a cleaner DOM to work with.